# Qt - Configuring interface through xml

Tags: javascript, c++, xml, qml, qt5

I have a local xml file telling me:

- how many "swiping" pages my interface must have
- for any page, how many rows
- for any row, how many columns
  (any column will contain a label and a value which depend on the attributes that you find between the nodes )

This is a template:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <parameters version="2.0">
      <page pageNum = "2">
           <row colNum = "1">
                <column>
                     <id>00001</id>
                     <name>parameterName</name>
                     <type>parameterType</type>
                     <value>parameterValue</value>
                     <min>0</min>
                     <max>100</max>
                     <step>1</step>
                </column>
           </row>
           <row colNum = "2">
                <column>
                     <id>00002</id>
                     <name>parameterName</name>
                     <type>parameterType</type>
                     <value>parameterValue</value>
                     <min>0</min>
                     <max>100</max>
                     <step>1</step>
                </column>
                <column>
                     <id>00003</id>
                     <name>parameterName</name>
                     <type>parameterType</type>
                     <value>parameterValue</value>
                     <min>0</min>
                     <max>100</max>
                     <step>1</step>
                </column>
           </row>
      </page>
      <page>
           <!-- ... etc ... -->
      </page>
 </parameters>
```

After some research I've found in some forums that XmlListModel is not suitable.
How can I do, considering that I am working in Qt?

Here https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg12284.html I found something interesting, however for reading the xml file is used XMLHttpRequest, which I can't use, as my xml file is just local!

Can someone help me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: But what is the actual question? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The actual question is how to configure my qml-based interface through this xml file! Qml has XmlListModel, but it cannot be used for a complex thing like this...

Comment: What's the sense in converting xml to qml instead of directly creating qml? And why `XmlListModel` not good for that?

Comment: My task is not converting! It is configuring my view on the basis of a local xml file!

Comment: Usually you do that in a special JSON-dialect called QML. Using this dialect is especially beneficail as it can be directly parsed by the JIT instead of having to rely on a tool that first translates from XML into this JSON-dialect, to finally use it.

Comment: I need to write in Qml a code that allow my view to change on the basis of that local xml file...

Comment: Ok, but how is this file created? It looks like you have some flaw in the application design. Anyway, you have several ways to accomplish the task. `XmlListModel` as you already said. Creating custom item(singleton?) in C++ when you have all the Qt power (QDomDocument, QXmlReader etc.) to parse XML and so create QML items.

Comment: Could you post me some links to read? I am experiencing difficulties in finding some good documentation... I'd like to find some examples...

Comment: I agree with @folibis that this doesn't sound like it couldn't be handled by `XmlListModel`. One instance with a query for the pages used with a `Repeater` or similar to create the pages. Each page with another instance of the model for the rows of that page, with the column fields as each entry's properties.

Comment: Could you answer me with a template code? XmlListModel is fine if working!! :-) @folibis

Comment: Could you answer me with a template code? @KevinKrammer

Comment: @Elena edited my answer but you should really consider just doing the parsing in C++

Comment: @KevinKrammer thanks! I am going to try in couple of days and leaving my feedback! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this can almost certainly be done with `XmlListModel` (see comment on the question) this would be fairly wasteful as each instance of the model needs to do all the parsing and querying.

One `XmlListModel` would provide the input for how many pages there are

```
XmlListModel {
    query: "/parameters/page"
}
```

Each page would then have a model that extracts the rows for that page (query not tested)

```
XmlListModel {
    // pageNum is a property set on each page, e.g. via the model.index of the Repeater generating the pages
    query: "/parameters/page[@pageNum=" + pageNum + "]/row"

    XmlRole { name: "id"; query: "column/id/string()" }
    // ... and so on
}
```

However, I think the best way forward is to create a custom `QAbstractListModel` subclass that can represent the rows of a single page.

Then an object with a list property of that type can be used as the model for the pages, each page using its "row model".

Parsing done only once, e.g. with `QXmlStreamReader` to build the list of "row models" and getting the contents of each of them.